# Azure mobile service getCurrentUser

Tags: java, android, authentication, azure-mobile-services, azure-cloud-services

I have got a .net backend Azure Mobile Service. I have been trying to getting current user information from Android client. I am using the following code

```
private void authenticate() {

    LoginRequest login = new LoginRequest();
    login.setUsername(txtUsername.getText().toString());
    login.setPassword(txtPassword.getText().toString());
    ServiceConstant.mClient.invokeApi("CustomLogin", login, LoginRequest.class,
            new ApiOperationCallback<LoginRequest>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(LoginRequest result,
                        Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                    if (exception == null) {
                        try 
                        {
                            if (chkRemember.isChecked()) 
                            {
                                cacheUserToken(ServiceConstant.mClient.getCurrentUser());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cache success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG, "cache fail");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "cache fail",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "giris basarili " + result);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DeviceScanActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "login fail" + exception);
                        alert("login", "success\n" + exception);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

When I try to get current user it returns null. What should I do for getting current user information. I am very newbie to Azure Mobile Service and I haven't any idea for resolve this problem.

Comment: Have you set up authentication yet? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-android-get-started-users/

Comment: Yes, I have already added the authentication code

Answer (score 1):

This custom login code is based on a custom API, so it's result doesn't get stored automatically like when you work with the built-in login functions.

You need to set the mClient's CurrentUser field manually when you get the result from your API.

If you were following [this custom auth tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/), the return type will actually match the client's MobileServiceUser type, and you can set the value . For more detail, see the last section of that tutorial, titled "Sign in using custom authentication from the client."

Comment: first of all thank you for answer, I was following the insruction and it is going as follows http://imgur.com/Niq00pO after this when I try to cache user mAuthenticationToken value seems null like this http://imgur.com/mpPGiTi, is this a problem? what can I do from now on, do you give me some idea

Comment: Looks like the types aren't aligned exactly. The easiest solution is probably to treat the response as a simple JSON object and pull out the userID and authenticationToken values. You can just set those on a new MobileServiceUser and then assign MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser to it.

Comment: How can I pull these values from response.getContent() ?

Comment: I think in your code you are using the LoginRequest as the result type when it should be something like MobileServiceUser. The call should look like  `invokeApi("CustomLogin", login, MobileServiceUser.class, new ApiOperationCallback<MobileServiceUser>() ...`, and then you will be able to get the values from the `result` object. This blog might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2015/05/06/sign-in-to-mobile-services-using-custom-authentication-from-a-windows-client.aspx